# Split string by punctuation marks in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to do the following:

```
String[] Res = Text.split("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+");
```

But, I always get a few words with space before them. 
How can I parse the sentence without getting spaces and other punctuation marks as a part of the word itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn’t provide a sample input which can reproduce the problem I can only guess. I can’t see why the regex you provided should ever leave spaces in the result unless you are using non-ASCII white-space or punctuation characters. The reason that is both `\\p{Punct}` and `\\s` are POSIX character classes limited to ASCII, e.g. `\\s` will not match `\u00a0`. Use `[\\p{IsPunctuation}\\p{IsWhite_Space}]+` if non-ASCII punctuation and white-space characters are your problem.

Example

```
String text="Some\u00a0words stick together⁈";
String[] res1 = text.split("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res1));
String[] res2 = text.split("[\\p{IsPunctuation}\\p{IsWhite_Space}]+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res2));
```

will produce:

```
[Some words, stick, together⁈]
[Some, words, stick, together]
```

Comment: I've just seen that you have the white space in the second example also :(

Comment: Huh? Where do you see white-space?

Comment: The comma and the single space right after the comma come from `Arrays.toString`. You may use `for(String s:res2) System.out.println('"'+s+'"');` if you want to see it in a different way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [`trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) all the Strings in the array before using them. This will eliminate all the leading and trailing white spaces.

```
str = str.trim();
```

In your case

```
for(String str : Res) {
    str = str.trim();
    // use str now, without any white spaces
}
```

If you need to keep the punctuations also, then, you need to use the [`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) which takes in the `boolean` value of keeping the delimiters or not.

Comment: Trim is great unless it won't save me from other punctuation marks. Will it?

Comment: Since you're splitting on the punctuation marks, you wont get them in the Strings. Only if you use a `StringTokenizer`, you've the option to get the delimiters as well.

Comment: I'm keeping the punctuation marks and the spaces. I just showed the simplest version of my problem that does not work.

Comment: You need to use `StringTokenizer` in that case. See the edit in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For removing spaces trailing or leading whatever it may be use

```
   String str=" java ";
   str = str.trim();
```