# How to match any word but ignore those that starts with multiple whitespaces?

Tags: java, regex

What I am trying to achieve is to match all words in text, but ignore those words in line (before new line) that start with 4 whitespaces.

---

**Example**

Text file to find words:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut 
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

    This must NOT be matched. Because it has 4 whitespaces at the beginning.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
```

So, the words in following line should be NOT considered to match pattern:

```
This must NOT be matched. Because it has 4 whitespaces at the beginning.
```

**Code**

Here is my regex and it can find all words:

```
\\b[A-Za-z]+\\b
```

I know that in Java's RegEx syntax there is `except` which is `^` symbol but I only know how to use it in more simple expressions.

Comment: How do you process the single lines? If at any time the line is in a `String` simple skipp the check if the string start with fout spaces.

Comment: @SubOptimal I read the text from file and assign it to a string variable, so all my text is stored in one String variable

Comment: Do you want to match all _lines_ or all _words_ which don't begin with 4 spaces?

Comment: @RDay I want to match all words in line

Comment: `^(?!\s)[\w .]+` this will match one line at a time so you can run loop, but it will skipp the line which you want, hope it helps

Comment: @IliaAptsiauri that RegEx stops at the comma in the first line of the example.

Comment: @RDay you are right sorry, I am posting from the phone just a sec will modify it

Comment: @RDay '^(?!\s)[\w\s!-~]+' this should select all punctuation marks as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe following snippet could be a basis for what you want to achieve.

```
String[] lines = {"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do",
    "eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut",
    "enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris",
    "nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    "",
    "    This must NOT be matched. Because it has 4 whitespaces at the beginning.",
    "",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Ut enim ad minim veniam."};
for (String line : lines) {
    if (!line.startsWith("    ")) {
        String[] words = line.split("[\\p{IsPunctuation}\\p{IsWhite_Space}]+");
        System.out.println("words = " + Arrays.toString(words));
    }
}
```

output

```
words = [Lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit, amet, consectetur, adipiscing, elit, sed, do]
words = [eiusmod, tempor, incididunt, ut, labore, et, dolore, magna, aliqua, Ut]
words = [enim, ad, minim, veniam, quis, nostrud, exercitation, ullamco, laboris]
words = [nisi, ut, aliquip, ex, ea, commodo, consequat]
words = []
words = []
words = [Lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit, amet, Ut, enim, ad, minim, veniam]
```

PS: the regex has been borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811111/split-string-by-punctuation-marks-in-java)

Comment: I've got the main idea, appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

The following should do that

```
(?<!\s{4})\\b[A-Za-z]+\\b
```

It begins with a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) so it won't match anything with `\s{4}` preceding it.

Comment: It is ignoring only first word after 4 spaces and takes all after that, but thanks for your help anyway, now I know that I need to read more about **negative lookbehind**. I think this is because I read text in one single string variable.